# Can Owncloud 9's tags be read with webdav?

Tags: webdav, owncloud

From webdav, we would like to read the tags put on a file in the Owncloud 9 web interface
Secondary, from webdav, we would also like to search via tags, just like it is possible in the web interface.

Has anyone seen if this is possible?

We cannot find such functionality in the mobile api's either

Thanks!

/Aksel